# UltiDev Cassini and <system.webServer> web.config settings

Tags: configuration, web-config, webserver, cassini, ultidev

MS Cassini Development Web Server is a nice product that executes web requests in a similar way that IIS7 does. Every request (event for static content) goes through the same .Net pipeline without exception. All custom HttpModule can handle any request.

But sometimes you don't want these modules to execute for certain content (most often static content). In this regard, MS Cassini doesn't read/obey `<system.webServer>` web.config settings like IIS7 does. I'm particularly interested in these settings.

```
<system.webServer>
    ...
    <handlers />
    <modules />
</syste.webServer>
```

**Does [UltiDev's Cassini](http://www.ultidev.com/products/Cassini/index.htm) (a separate payable product upgraded from MS Cassini) web server read these settings and execute as the web.config tells it to?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cassini doesn't behave like IIS7, but like IIS6. So you should use `<system.web>` sections instead of `<system.webServer>`:

```
<system.web>
    ...
    <httpHandlers />
    <httpModules />
</system.web>
```

The reason all requests go through the ASP.NET pipeline is because it is hardwired to do that (like having wildcard mapping on in IIS6)

Comment: MS Cassini is more like IIS6 but it somehow has execution pipeline of IIS7 as it appears to me. But I'm talking about UltiDev's Cassini, not Microsoft development web server a.k.a. cassini. UltiDev's product is a lot more enhanced AFAIK. And I'd like to know wehther that product is more advanced in terms of my question.

Comment: MS Cassini and UltiDev Cassini both use the IIS6 pipeline (only difference being that all requests go to ASP.NET). UltiDev's product uses the same core as Microsoft's, but it offers a few extra features like the ability to run it as a service, install multiple sites, etc. But it still uses the same core, which is IIS6 compatible (so you have to use IIS6 config sections)

Answer (score 0):

My company makes a product called the [Neokernel Web Server](http://www.neokernel.com) that runs ASP.NET web applications, but static content is served without using the ASP.NET pipeline. It's a commercial product, but a free evaluation license is available.