# ASP.NET App Debug: Breakpoint currently not hit

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, iis

I want to debug a ASP.NET application (Custom IHttpHandler) with Visual Studio 2008 and IIS7.

I compile the source, start debugging (F5) and IE loads. But my breakpoint (in method ProcessRequest()) is disabled. I get the error:

> The breakpoint will not currently be hit. 
>   No symbols have been loaded for this document.

I have no idea about ASP.NET programming. Do i have to set anything in IIS?

The PDB files are there. I wanted to check the symbol load status of my DLL but I couldn't find it.

When I open "Debug->Windows->Modules" I can't see my DLL in the list.
Only Windows DLLs and assemlies from GAC and so on.

Am I missing something?

Comment: Are you running as Administrator? You'll need admin permissions to attach to the IIS processes.

Comment: @Rup: yes i run VS2008 in admin mode.

Comment: got it.
i had to open a page with an specific file ending while debugging. as soon as i opened the right page my ddl loaded and the breakpoint activated.
well, i do really know nothing about asp programming...
thanks for the quick anwers anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved it.

I had to open a page with an specific file ending while debugging. As soon as I opened the right page my DDL loaded and the breakpoint activated.

Answer (score 3):

Visual Studio -> Debug -> Attach to process

w3wp.exe

More info here: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/ProcessAttache.aspx

Comment: there is no w3wp.exe. i don't want to debug an app that is hosted on an iis. the Visual Studio project is configured to start the VS Dev Server to host the app.

Comment: wait, you said Visual Studio 2008 and IIS7, if there is site hosted in IIS there would be w3wp.exe. Sorry if I misunderstood you

Answer (score 3):

For the archive: a breakpoint is only activated, once the corresponding assembly was loaded in the process space. So in order to enable a breakpoint which was set on a code line inside a DLL, you must run your app to the place, where the DLL is loaded. The breakpoint will than get recognized by the debugger and ungrayed in VS.

Answer (score 2):

The problem for me turned out to be that the Properties->Build->Optimize code checkbox had been turned on in the Debug configuration. Turned it off, rebuilt, and debugging worked as normal.

Answer (score 1):

Have you registered the HttpHandler in the `<system.web>` section instead of `<system.webServer>`?

In `web.config`:

```
<system.web>
    ...
    <httpHandlers>
        <add verb="GET" path="MyHandler.ashx" type="MyHandler, MyAssembly" />
    ...
    </httpHandlers>
</system.web>
```

#### See Also

- [UltiDev Cassini and
   web.config
  settings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1168881/ultidev-cassini-and-system-webserver-web-config-settings)
- [HttpHandler in IIS7 and
  Visual Studio 2010](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3487758/httphandler-in-iis7-and-visual-studio-2010)